# Inserting html codes in Wordpress custom meta Fields

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have created custom meta fields in the functions.php file. The problem I am facing here is that when ever a html code such as `<a href="example.com"></a>` is inserted and saved, the meta box incorporates the code and the box now only displays `<a href="`. If the user were to then save the post again `<a href=` will be added to the page which can lead to numerous errors. Is there a way to format the metafield to contain the codes instead of merging it as part of the meta field markup it self.

My meta fields are currently like this

```
"example_name" => array(
"name" => "example_name",
"std" => "",
"title" => "Example",
"description" => "Example text")
```

Please your help will be much appreciated..also I'm looking for codes, not a plugin for my solution.

The HTMl is inserted like this

```
if($meta_box_value == "")
$meta_box_value = $meta_box['std'];
echo'<input type="hidden" name="'.$meta_box['name'].'_noncename" id="'.$meta_box['name'].'_noncename" value="'.wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ).'" />';
echo'<h2 style=" margin:0px; padding:0px 3px; font-style:normal; font-family:Tahoma; font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;">'.$meta_box['title'].'</h2>';
echo'<input type="text" name="'.$meta_box['name'].'_value" value="'.$meta_box_value.'" size="95" /><br />';
echo'<p><label for="'.$meta_box['name'].'_value">'.$meta_box['description'].'</label></p>';
```

Comment: How is the html code inserted?

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, I just edited the question to show the html implementation

Comment: hm. maybe use htmlspecialchars() ?

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much! You saved me a lot of trouble and time with such a simple solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `htmlspecialchars()`-function in PHP.